# Drag-Drop within UITableView like Trello iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, drag-and-drop

How do I achieve drag and drop functionality between UITableViews on iOS like the Trello app.

For Android, I have found a library [here](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) which perfectly serves my need.

Is there any library to achieve this on iOS?

Comment: Hey @kalpesh  did you found any library for that ???

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya I used BetweenKit framework and created a POC. You can check the same here: https://github.com/KalpeshTalkar/DragDropBoard
Please let me know if you have any better option. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Kalpesh you save my day... :)

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya welcome :)

Comment: @Kalpesh have you found the soution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Library. [FMMoveTableView](https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView)

It will serve your purpose in iOS.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Can I drag cell from one tableview and drop it to another tableview usnig this library?

Comment: you need to use CollectionView for that. Just took the logic of drag from this library and drop the items anywhere in collection view.

Comment: Is there any library to do so with collectionviews?